# Inside of left slider, and right side mouse wheel don't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript

In my code below, inside of left slider, and right side mouse wheel work in Chrome but don't work in Firefox. Can anyone see what's going on?

```
<script>
var bg_slider = jQuery('#slider').val();
var bg_va = jQuery('#nave_value').val();
var bg_d = parseInt(bg_va); 
var button = jQuery('#btn_value').val();
var bg_c = parseInt(button); 

var scall = jQuery('#bg_scall').val();
var bg_easy = parseInt(scall); 

var space = jQuery('#spc_value').val();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var carousel = jQuery("#coverflow").flipster({
        style: bg_slider,
        nav: bg_d,
        buttons: bg_c,
        spacing: space,
        scrollwheel:bg_easy,
    });
});

var bg_a = jQuery('#bg_autoplay').val();
var iNum = parseInt(bg_a); 
var bg_t = jQuery('#bg_show_title').val();
var title = parseInt(bg_t); 
var bg_s = jQuery('#bg_show_navel').val();
var navel = parseInt(bg_s); 
var bg_pl = jQuery('#bg_show_play').val();
var show = parseInt(bg_pl); 
var html5lightbox_options = {
    autoplay: iNum,
    showtitle: title,
    shownavigation: navel,
    showplaybutton: show,
};

</script>
```

I use Flipster jQuery plugin v1.1.1

Comment: Please create a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - maybe even making the javascript in your question [a runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) by including the HTML markup.

Comment: I have attached above minimal code

Comment: Sry for a delay .please help me

Comment: @murugesh can you create fiddler for that?

Comment: its not passable  create fiddler for that because its a very big task.

Comment: Could you add to the snippet in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265457/images-in-bootstrap-carousel-wont-show-up/41268616#41268616) - add flipster components, as well as elements with id attributes *nave_value*, *slider*, *bg_scall*, etc.?

Comment: its k no prblm its fixed